# jquery templating - import a file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, mustache

I'm working with backbone.js, but as far as I've seen, it doesn't care what templating system you use. Currently I'm trying out mustache.js, but I'm open to other ones. I'm a little annoyed though with the way I have to put a template into a string:

```
var context = {
    name: this.model.get('name'),
    email: this.model.get('email')
}

var template = "<form>Name<input name='name' type='text' value='{{name}}' />Email<input name='email' type='text' value='{{email}}' /></form>";

var html = Mustache.to_html(template, context);
    $(this.el).html(html);
    $('#app').html(this.el);
```

I'd like if I could load it from a different file or something somehow. I want to be able to have template files in order to simplify things. For example, if I put it all in a string, I can't have breaks (well I can have html breaks, but that's not the point). After the line starts to get very long, it becomes unmanageable.

Tips?

Comment: Have you looked at jquery.tmpl plugin? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated (4/11/14):**

As answered by OP below:

> Unfortunately, the jQuery team has moved the templating functionality out of jQuery Core. The code is still available as a library here: [github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl](http://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl) and here: [github.com/borismoore/jsrender](http://github.com/borismoore/jsrender)

**Original Answer:**

I just used this a couple of hours ago:
http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

It's an official jQuery plugin(i.e. the devs endorse it).

This is the function you need to use for loading templates from things other than strings: http://api.jquery.com/template/

Here's the code to have a template in HTML:

```
<script id="titleTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <li>${Name}</li>
</script>
___________

// Compile the inline template as a named template
$( "#titleTemplate" ).template( "summaryTemplate" );

function renderList() {
  // Render the movies data using the named template: "summaryTemplate"
  $.tmpl( "summaryTemplate", movies ).appendTo( "#moviesList" );
}
```

It's in a `<script>` tag, because that's not visible by default.
Note the type="text/x-jquery-tmpl". If you omit that, it will try to parse it as JavaScript(and fail horribly).

Also note that "loading from a different file" is essentially the same as "reading a file" and then "loading from a string".

Comment: These links are now dead.

Comment: Unfortunately, the jQuery team has moved the templating functionality out of jQuery Core. The code is still available as a library here: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl and here: https://github.com/borismoore/jsrender

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

I just found this jQuery plugin - http://markdalgleish.com/projects/tmpload/ Does exactly what you want, and can be coupled with `$.tmpl`

---

I have built a lightweight template manager that loads templates via Ajax, which allows you to separate the templates into more manageable modules. It also performs simple, in-memory caching to prevent unnecessary HTTP requests. (I have used jQuery.ajax here for brevity)

```
var TEMPLATES = {};

var Template = {

  load: function(url, fn) {
    if(!TEMPLATES.hasOwnProperty(url)) {
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
          TEMPLATES[url] = data;
          fn(data);
        }
      });
    } else {
      fn(TEMPLATES[url]);
    }
  },

  render: function(tmpl, context) {
    // Apply context to template string here
    // using library such as underscore.js or mustache.js
  }

};
```

You would then use this code as follows, handling the template data via callback:

```
Template.load('/path/to/template/file', function(tmpl) {
  var output = Template.render(tmpl, { 'myVar': 'some value' });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

We are using jqote2 with backbone because it's faster than jQuery's, as you say there are many :)

We have all our templates in a single tpl file, we bind to our template_rendered so we can add jquery events etc etc

```
App.Helpers.Templates = function() {

  var loaded = false;
  var templates = {};

  function embed(template_id, parameters) {
    return $.jqote(templates[template_id], parameters);
  }

  function render(template_id, element, parameters) {
    var render_template = function(e) {
      var r = embed(template_id, parameters);
      $(element).html(r);
      $(element).trigger("template_rendered");
      $(document).unbind(e);
    };

    if (loaded) {
      render_template();
    } else {
      $(document).bind("templates_ready", render_template);
    }
  }

  function load_templates() {
    $.get('/javascripts/backbone/views/templates/templates.tpl', function(doc) {
      var tpls = $(doc).filter('script');
      tpls.each(function() {
        templates[this.id] = $.jqotec(this);
      });
      loaded = true;
      $(document).trigger("templates_ready");
   });
  }

  load_templates();

  return {
    render: render,
    embed: embed
  };

}();
```

They look like

```
<script id="table" data-comment="generated!!!!! to change please change table.tpl">
<![CDATA[
]]>
</script>
```